# How to use shell_exec() function in a php domain?

Tags: php, exec, safe-mode, php-safe-mode

I found the `shell_exec()` function is disabled in my remote server.

Is there is any other way or tips to execute the `shell_exec()` function?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are some alternatives (eg `system()`, `exec()`, `passthru()`, backtick operator), but my guess is that they will be disabled too :)

I think you're out of luck here!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there is any other way or tips to execute the shell_exec() function?

Probably no, because the function is usually disabled for security reasons.

You would have to talk to your provider, or - if possible - look for a PHP library that does what you want to do without needing `shell_exec()`

Answer (score 0):

**You can see ref of official documentation**

```
[http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php][1]
```